# Required a spacing while merging two identical column values

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to merge 2 column values - It's working good. But, there is no space between 2 values. Below is my code. Please let me know where i have to correct:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvctime = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvctime.Name = cmbColumn1.Text;
        dgvctime.HeaderText = cmbColumn1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvctime);

        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvctime);

        int rowadded = 0;

        for (int RowCount = 1; RowCount <= strfile.Length - 1; RowCount++)
        {
            if (strfile[RowCount].ToString() != "")
            {
                if (RowCount != 0)
                {
                    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    string[] column = strfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                    rowadded = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i < column.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                        if ((cmbColumn1.SelectedIndex == ((i - 1) / 2)) || (cmbColumn2.SelectedIndex == ((i - 1) / 2)))
                        {
                            if (rowadded == 0)
                            {
                                rowadded = 1;
                                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                            }
                            if (column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                            {
                                //dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value += column[i].ToString();
                                dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value += column[i].ToString();
                   `         }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: `+= " " + ...`? What two values are you talking about? Please read [ask] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line ...

```
dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value += " " + column[i].ToString();
```

Comment: @Aditya, If this helped your problem, remember to click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a short update

```
dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value += " " + column[i].ToString();
```